# Fixed navigation bar overlap issue

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two navigation bars: one shows on one set of pages and another shows on a different set of pages (using an if... else statement in application.html.erb.) One of the two navigation bars has a fixed position at the top and as a result overlaps the following text. I could solve this by adding `body {margin-top: 25px;}` to the stylesheet. However, the problem then is that it also does this for the pages that have a different navigation bar, which has not a fixed position resulting in a 25px high white bar a the top of those pages.

How could I include the `margin-top` for the body only for those pages where that specific navigation bar is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding `margin-bottom` to the specific navbar?

EDIT:
You can wrap all your content in some `div`, and add dynamically class to it (same condition like you have in navbar).

`<div class="<%= condition ? first_class : second_class %>">`

And add appropriate margins to those clsass.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It places the fixed navbar on top of the body, so body isn't relative to the margin of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a new stylesheet for that bit of code, and include it with the navbar it's needed for?

You wouldn't even have to change your if-statement.

Comment: But wouldn't Rails, because of its asset pipeline, automatically include the stylesheet for the entire application and apply it to all pages?